# Android I have this error "Bitcode is not in proper container format (raw or wrapper)"?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, renderscript

Hello i am trying to make a water live wallpaper using renderscript, but i get this error. I think that has to do with the RS file(this file is in raw folder as it should be).

RenderScript "Bitcode is not in proper container format (raw or wrapper)"

Does anybody know how to fix this ??

Answer (score 0):

The .rs file should be placed with your other application sources (and not in the res/raw folder). The generated .bc file will be placed there automatically by the compiler.